# Can't get the CSS nth term to work

Tags: html, css, responsive-design, fluid-layout, css-selectors

I realise i have posted couple of questions on floating , nearly near just have one more question on the nth term..

I am trying to adjust some responsive floats using the nth term and widths but im struggling to change the following.

When you reduce the screen size to under 600px i need the two boxes to be displayed as 3 equally boxes, not two. I am struggling to accomplish this using widths and use of nth term.

Im trying to achieve the following.

```
4 boxes above 900px +px
3 boxes above 600px - 900px
2 boxes 460px - 600px
1 box 0- 460px
```

If anyone could help it would be great.

http://jsfiddle.net/sFApC/

```css
.display-box{
  position: relative;
  clear: left;
  background: #fff;
  -webkit-border-radius: 4px;
  -moz-border-radius: 4px;
  border-radius: 4px;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 1px 2px rgba(0,0,0,0.09);
  -moz-box-shadow: 0 1px 2px rgba(0,0,0,0.09);
  box-shadow: 0 1px 2px rgba(0,0,0,0.09);
  padding: 10px 10px 30px 10px;
  border: 1px solid #d1d1d1;
  }
  .display-box:hover{
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 10px 6px -6px #b5b5b5;
    -moz-box-shadow: 0 10px 6px -6px #b5b5b5;
    box-shadow: -1px 1px 11px 2px #b5b5b5;
    cursor: pointer;
    border: 1px solid #c6c6c6 ;
  }
  .display-user{
    max-width: 20px !important;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    float: left;
  }
  .user-name{
    float: left;
    font-weight: bold;
    margin: 6px 0 0 6px;
    }
    .content-upload img{
      height: 20%;
    }

#upload-container {
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 970px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  margin-top: 20px;
}
#upload-container ul {
  width: 100%;
  *zoom: 1;
}
#upload-container ul li {
  float: left;
  margin-right: -100%;
  width: 93%;
}

#upload-container ul li a:hover {
  text-decoration: none;
}

#upload-container ul li span {
  font-size: 16px;
  line-height: 22px;
  display: block;
  padding-bottom: 30px;
}
#upload-container ul li img {
  width: 100%;
}
#upload-container ul li:nth-child(1n+1) {
  margin-left: 0%;
  margin-bottom: 5.85%;
  clear: both;
  overflow: hidden;
  *zoom: 1;
}

@media screen and (min-width: 460px) {
  #upload-container ul li {
    float: left;
    margin-right: -100%;
    width: 42.08%;
  }
  #upload-container ul li span {
    padding-bottom: 10px;
  }
  #upload-container ul li:nth-child(2n+1) {
    margin-left: 0%;
    margin-bottom: 3.85%;
    clear: both;
    overflow: hidden;
    *zoom: 1;
  }
  #upload-container ul li:nth-child(2n+2) {
    margin-left: 51.93%;
    margin-bottom: 3.85%;
    clear: none;
  }
}
@media screen and (min-width: 600px) {
  #upload-container ul li {
    float: left;
    margin-right: -100%;
    width: 45.08%;
  }
  #upload-container ul li span {
    padding-bottom: 10px;
  }
  #upload-container ul li:nth-child(2n+1) {
    margin-left: 0%;
    margin-bottom: 3.85%;
    clear: both;
    overflow: hidden;
    *zoom: 1;
  }
  #upload-container ul li:nth-child(2n+2) {
    margin-left: 51.93%;
    margin-bottom: 3.85%;
    clear: none;
  }
}

@media screen and (min-width: 900px) {
  #upload-container ul li {
    float: left;
    margin-right: -100%;
    width: 20.8%;
  }
  #upload-container ul li span {
    padding-bottom: 0px;
  }
  #upload-container ul li:nth-child(4n+1) {
    margin-left: 0%;
    margin-bottom: 3.85%;
    clear: both;
    overflow: hidden;
    *zoom: 1;
  }
  #upload-container ul li:nth-child(4n+2) {
    margin-left: 25.96%;
    margin-bottom: 3.85%;
    clear: none;
  }
  #upload-container ul li:nth-child(4n+3) {
    margin-left: 51.93%;
    margin-bottom: 3.85%;
    clear: none;
  }
  #upload-container ul li:nth-child(4n+4) {
    margin-left: 77.89%;
    margin-bottom: 3.85%;
    clear: none;
  }
}
```

[image]

Comment: What do you want to achieve? What do you mean with "i need the two boxes to be displayed as 3 equally boxes, not two"? Which two boxes? Or do you mean columns? Please show an image or an example how it should look like.

Comment: Are you using media queries at all?

Comment: Hi, thanaks for your help. i have added a picture, yes im using media queries

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In `@media screen and (min-width: 600px)` query you have only 2 columns specified.

Quick fix:

```
@media screen and (min-width: 600px) {
  #upload-container ul li {
    float: left;
    margin-right: -100%;
    width: 27.73%;
  }
  #upload-container ul li span {
    padding-bottom: 10px;
  }
  #upload-container ul li:nth-child(3n+1) {
    margin-left: 0%;
    margin-bottom: 3.85%;
    clear: both;
    overflow: hidden;
    *zoom: 1;
  }
  #upload-container ul li:nth-child(3n+2) {
    margin-left: 34.29%;
    margin-bottom: 3.85%;
    clear: none;
  }
  #upload-container ul li:nth-child(3n+3) {
    margin-left: 68.59%;
    margin-bottom: 3.85%;
    clear: none;
  }
}
```

This is not pixel-perfect, but you can see 3 columns. You must just adjust margins and widths.

Working sample: http://jsfiddle.net/Ls8c6/1/

Answer (score 1):

Your css is incorrect, you are using the same thing for media screen with min-width:460 and media screen with min-width: 600.

Try to change your code, use this snippet for media screen and min-width of 600px:

```
@media screen and (min-width: 600px) {
    #upload-container ul li {
        float: left;
        margin-right: -100%;
        width: 25.8%;
        background-color: green;
    }
    #upload-container ul li span {
        padding-bottom: 0px;
    }
    #upload-container ul li:nth-child(3n+1) {
        margin-left: 0%;
        margin-bottom: 3.85%;
        clear: both;
        overflow: hidden;
        *zoom: 1;
    }
    #upload-container ul li:nth-child(3n+2) {
        margin-left: 30.96%;
        margin-bottom: 3.85%;
        clear: none;
    }
    #upload-container ul li:nth-child(3n+3) {
        margin-left: 61.93%;
        margin-bottom: 3.85%;
        clear: none;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I would rather skip the `@media` queries and just use `float: left` on `.display-box`. Together with a `width: 200px`, you would get roughly the expected behaviour.

```
.display-box {
    float: left;
    width: 200px;
}
```

This would need some margin and padding adjustments, of course. See modified [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sFApC/3/)

If you want exactly the given columns, I would still use `float: left`, but simplify the media queries to just give a relative width for `.display-box` and refactor the rest into the common CSS rules

```
.display-box {
    float: left;
    min-width: 200px;
    width: 80%;
}

@media screen and (min-width: 460px) {
    .display-box {
        width: 40%;
    }
}

@media screen and (min-width: 600px) {
    .display-box {
        width: 25%;
    }
}

@media screen and (min-width: 900px) {
    .display-box {
        width: 17%;
    }
}
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sFApC/5/)